# Tikz 3D node placement using \let in plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, plot, coordinates

I am facing a result you probably can help me with, here is my MWE (which gives the good output if I put the values manually):

```
    \documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz,esvect,tikz-3dplot}
    \usetikzlibrary{3d,calc,intersections}

    \begin{document} 

    \begin{tikzpicture}[x={(0.710cm,-0.410cm)},y={(0cm,0.820cm)},z={(-0.710cm,-0.410cm)}]

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\l}{4}

    %%%%%% Helicoidale 3 %%%%%%
    \coordinate (centre) at (4,1,0);
    \coordinate (centrezp) at ($(centre)+(0,0,\l/2)$) ;
    \coordinate (centrezm) at ($(centre)-(0,0,\l/2)$) ;

    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
    \draw let \p1=($(centrezp)-(centrezm)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)} in 
    [fill=white]
    ($(centrezp)+(\n1+90:\r)$) -- ($(centrezm)+(\n1+90:\r)$)
    arc[radius=\r,start angle=\n1+90 ,delta angle=180] -- ($(centrezp)+(\n1-90:\r)$)
    arc[radius=\r,start angle=\n1+270,delta angle=-540];
    \end{scope}
    \draw %
    let \p1=(centre) in 
    [domain=0:\l*pi, samples=80, smooth]
    plot ( {4 +cos((-2.2+\x/4) r)}, {1-sin((-2.2+\x/4) r)} , \x/pi-2) ;

    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

If you read that carefully you might have noticed I am not using the line

```
 let \p1=(centre) in
```

I have tried using that :

```
    plot ( {\x1 +cos((-2.2+\x/4) r)}, {\y1-sin((-2.2+\x/4) r)} , \x/pi-2) ;
```

But with no success, the plot it totally out of place. I have tried to display the content of \x1, it gives me a value in pt, which might be the issue since the rest should be in cm. But I can't find how to change it.

Can you help me ?

good result :

[image].

Bad result

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues. The first one is that by default the plot variable is `\x`, which clashes with `\x1` from calc. To solve this one, you can just use `variable=\t`, say, for the plot. The second issue is that for

```
 \coordinate (centre) at (4,1,0);
```

after `let \p1=(centre) in` the macro `\x1` does *not* evaluate to `4`but to the x coordinate of the projection of `(centre)` on the screen. However, you do not need this, nor `calc`. All you need is `shift={(centre)}` as in

```
\draw[shift={(centre)}] %
[domain=0:\l*pi, samples=80, smooth,variable=\t]
plot ( {cos((-2.2+\t/4) r)}, {-sin((-2.2+\t/4) r)} , \t/pi-2) ;
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,esvect,tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc,intersections}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(0.710cm,-0.410cm)},y={(0cm,0.820cm)},z={(-0.710cm,-0.410cm)}]

\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\l}{4}

%%%%%% Helicoidale 3 %%%%%%
\coordinate (centre) at (4,1,0);
\coordinate (centrezp) at ($(centre)+(0,0,\l/2)$) ;
\coordinate (centrezm) at ($(centre)-(0,0,\l/2)$) ;

\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
\draw let \p1=($(centrezp)-(centrezm)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)} in 
[fill=white]
($(centrezp)+(\n1+90:\r)$) -- ($(centrezm)+(\n1+90:\r)$)
arc[radius=\r,start angle=\n1+90 ,delta angle=180] -- ($(centrezp)+(\n1-90:\r)$)
arc[radius=\r,start angle=\n1+270,delta angle=-540];
\end{scope}
\draw[shift={(centre)}] %
   [domain=0:\l*pi, samples=80, smooth,variable=\t]
    plot ( {cos((-2.2+\t/4) r)}, {-sin((-2.2+\t/4) r)} , \t/pi-2) ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Let me also comment that one can retrieve the x component of the 3d declared coordinate. This is realized e.g. in the unofficial [3d tools library](https://github.com/tallmarmot/pgf/tree/master/experiments/Marmot/3dtools).

Comment: P.S. You are loading but not using `tikz-3dplot`. If you keep loading it, you no longer need to load the `3d` and `calc` libraries explicitly since they get loaded by the package.

Comment: Clear and perfectly on point, Thank you very much @Schrödinger's cat. Stack's community never disappoints.